# shell_exec() PHP de um script em Python

Tags: php, python

O script

```
<?php 

$output = shell_exec('py core003.py');
echo $output;

?>
```

Roda o script =>

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

O output é

```
3.0.1 (r301:69561, Feb 13 2009, 17:50:10) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que se eu rodar 'py core003.py' no PowerShell por exemplo, eu recebo

```
3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Não era pro output do php ser o mesmo do powershell?

Eu preciso mudar de 3.0.1 pra 3.6.0 (ou qualquer uma que eu escolher), é possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você provavelmente tem versões diferentes do Python instalado, note que no PowerShell você executou diretamente da pasta:

> c:\wampx64\www\python

O que provavelmente não é uma instalação global do Python, na verdade nem acho que deveria estar na pasta `www` (mas isto é outro problema), então quando você executa via PHP por `shell_exec` sem o caminho, ele procura a instalação global, que esta configurado na variavel do *sistema operacional*, chamada *PATH* (variavel de ambiente), então para que o PHP reconheça o mesmo que você fez no powershell, você pode simplesmente fazer assim:

```
<?php

$pypath = 'c:\wampx64\www\python\py';
$scriptpath = 'core003.py';

$output = shell_exec(escapeshellarg($pypath) . ' ' . escapeshellarg($scriptpath));
echo $output;
```

---

### Extra

Você não precisa instalar na pasta `www`, basta que o *Python* esteja nas variáveis de ambiente (environment variables), sendo Windows basta seguir o passo a passo:

- Clique com o direito do mouse/rato no <kbd>Meu Computador</kbd> e <kbd>Propriedades</kbd>
- No menu lateral esquerdo clique no <kbd>Configurações avançadas do sistema</kbd>
- Procure um botão chamado <kbd>Variáveis de ambiente</kbd>, clique nele
- Procure a variavel *PATH* e clique duas vezes, deve retornar algo como:

  > C:\Python3.0;C:\Python3.0\Scripts;C:\php;C:\Users\Latitude E6410\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Latitude E6410\AppData\Roaming\npm

No meu caso tenho o Python3, Composer, php e npm, no seu deve ser algo parecido, no caso você vai trocar o que estiver com Python (que provavelmente aponta para o seu Python 3.0.1) para a localização do seu Python mais atualizado, por exemplo:

> C:\wampx64\www\python;C:\wampx64\www\python\Scripts;C:\php;C:\Users\Latitude E6410\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Latitude E6410\AppData\Roaming\npm

Vá clicando em todos botões <kbd>Ok</kbd> até ter fechado todas janelas que abriram anteriormente, faça logoff no usuário do Windows e logue novamente, pronto deve funcionar o seu Python mais atualizado sem precisar apontar o caminho.

Comment: Obrigado, me salvou.
Quanto ao "problema" do Python estar no www, ele não ta não xD
valeu!

Comment: @LuanDevecchi apenas segui o que esta no seu screenshot, o que indica que esta na pasta www e deve haver mais de uma instalação.

Comment: Sim, realmente tenho.
Outra coisa, eu seto o conteúdo da pagina PHP em utf-8 e ainda continuo recebendo simbolos ao invés de acentos, acha que é algo relacionado ao script em py, ou eu errei?

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: @LuanDevecchi esse simbolos veem do $output ou de outro lugar?

Comment: Vêm do $output sim!

Comment: @LuanDevecchi tenta assim `echo utf8_encode($output);`